# Shortening code to create a JFrame

Tags: java, beginner, swing

I'm new to Java and have just started making `JFrame`s. I wrote a program for a game project I'm working on and would like help on where I can improve. I'm not new to programming, I also know HTML and Python well.

I believe one of the goals for all programmers is to make a useful/fun program as simple and short as possible.

I would like pointers/ideas/improvements for my Java program on how I can make it shorter, where I should aim for and how I can make it simpler.

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

    //Set Variables to make it easier for myself
    public static double VER = 1.0;
    public static String STATE = "ALPHA";
    public static int WIDTH = 400;
    public static int HEIGHT = 400;
    public static int SCALE = 1;

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        //Create JFrame
        JFrame launcher = new JFrame("Infinite Doom " + STATE + " " + VER);     
        launcher.pack();

        //Settings for JFrame
        launcher.setVisible(true);
        launcher.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        launcher.setResizable(false);
        launcher.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("Logo.png").getImage());  
        launcher.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //Check Screen Res and centre window
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        launcher.setLocation(dim.width/2-launcher.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-launcher.getSize().height/2);
         }
    }
```

Comment: "as simple and short as possible", pffft... you apparently don't know me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to improve your game is to actually have a game. =)

You should probably think about the design of your game a little more.

1. What type of game are you actually going to make?
2. What user interface elements does your game require?

Putting the `JFrame` logic into your `main` method seems like a bad idea no matter what you're planning on. You should either create a class that has a `JFrame` as a member data field or a class that extends from `JFrame`. This would make your code more modular.

Comment: Yeah am working on that XD

Answer (score 4):

Just about the only thing I could comment on is your indentation the last two brackets

```
        launcher.setLocation(dim.width/2-launcher.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-launcher.getSize().height/2);
         }
    }
```

should be:

```
        launcher.setLocation(dim.width/2-launcher.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2launcher.getSize().height/2);
     }
}
```

Your variables:
`VER`, `STATE`, `WIDTH`, `HEIGHT` and `SCALE` could be set to final.

And last but maybe irrelevant. `SCALE` is not used, but maybe you're going to use it later. What do it know. :)

Comment: Yeah am planning to implement scale later in the project and i will fix the brackets and set the variables to final, thanks for the help!

Comment: So I looked again at the project and the brackets where fine. Must have been a copy and paste thing.